# Error 1265 Data truncated for column 'status' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running mySql database version 5.5.27 with `sql_mode` set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_ALL_TABLES`

My column named `status` was defined as:

```
ENUM('status1','status2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'status1'
```

an everything worked perfectly

After i altered column with

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN `status`
  ENUM('status1','status2','status3') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'status1';
```

Get no error. But when I tried to update some record o new 'status3', mysql gives me

```
1265 Data truncated for column 'status' at row 1
```

Even when I change column type to VARCHAR(45) I still cant update records with any value that wasn't in first enum list.
Any thought? Thanks

Comment: It works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e670c/1

Comment: @Mihai Your example worked for me as well, which prompted me that bug is in my db, and it was. I did not noticed I have trigger which inserts status in audit table, which had to be updated with new status as well. Thanks :)